# Allow mouse pointer to move off-screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, mouse

I want to allow my mouse cursor to be able to move anywhere on-screen or off-screen. I want to turn off whatever forces the mouse to stay on screen.

Comment: I am sure there is no way to do that. I am just installing a new Insider update and got the regular black screen on the way, so nothing user oriented running and the mouse pointer is tied to the edges and not beyond. That is with no software running so very doubtful you could make this work.

Comment: @John what about with 3rd party software?

Comment: You can't do this easily because you're at your physical bounds when your mouse is at the edge of the screen. What you need to do is trick Windows into thinking there is another display. This used to be able to be done fairly easily, but all options seem to be fixed in Windows 10. To trick Windows into thinking there is another display, you can try buying a [dummy plug](https://rb.gy/azmdro).

Answer (score 1):

I have looked over several articles and the mouse cannot be moved off screen.

I am just installing a new Insider update and got two regular black screens during the update (separated in time), so nothing user oriented running and the mouse pointer is tied to the edges and not beyond. That is with no software running.

My research confirms that there is no practical way you could make this work.

Users who are regular (not highly computer literate) would be very confused by this. There is no mouse option (3 different kinds plus touchpads here) to allow this.

Finally, once off screen (mouse needs screen to locate itself), how would it ever get back. It couldn't

No, not possible. That is certainly what I find.